# Matplotlib Animation for custom artist classes

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

## Goal

Hi,
I am trying to animate a complex figure with several subplots and have started testing with the [artist animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation) and the [function animation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) methods.

For now, my goal is to have the subplot on the left show a moving colored line (not the problem) and the subplot on the right show an updated representation of a brain scan (the problem). Static, this looks something like this.

```
# Imports
import nilearn as nil
from nilearn import plotting as nlp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

window = np.arange(0,200-50)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
a = ax.axvspan(window[0], window[0]+50, color='blue', alpha=0.5)

ay = fig.add_subplot(122)
b = nlp.plot_stat_map(nil.image.index_img(s_img, 0), axes=ay, colorbar=False, display_mode='x', cut_coords=(0,))
```

[image: Static version of what I'd like to display]

## Problem

As you can see, I am using [nilearn](http://nilearn.github.io/) for plotting the brain image. For some reason, the nilearn object from `plot_stat_map` does not have an attribute `set_visible` unlike the matplotlib object from `axvspan`.

So when I attempt a simple animation like so:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
ay = fig.add_subplot(122)
iml = list()

for i in np.arange(50):
    a = ax.axvspan(window[i], window[i]+50, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
    b = nlp.plot_stat_map(nil.image.index_img(s_img, i), axes=ay)
    iml.append((a,b))

ani = animation.ArtistAniTruemation(fig, iml, interval=50, blit=False,
    repeat_delay=1000)
```

it crashes with the following error:

```
/home/surchs/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.pyc in _init_draw(self)
    974         for f in self.new_frame_seq():
    975             for artist in f:
--> 976                 artist.set_visible(False)
    977                 # Assemble a list of unique axes that need flushing
    978                 if artist.axes not in axes:

AttributeError: 'OrthoSlicer' object has no attribute 'set_visible'
```

Makes sense, nilearn does maybe not conform to matplotlibs expectations. So I try the function animation method like so:

```
def show_things(i, window, ax, ay):
    ax.axvspan(window[i], window[i]+50, color='blue', alpha=0.5)
    nlp.plot_stat_map(nil.image.index_img(s_img, i), axes=ay, colorbar=False, display_mode='x', cut_coords=(0,))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax.set_xlim([0, 200])
ay = fig.add_subplot(122)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, show_things, interval=10, blit=False, fargs=(window, ax, ay))
```

Although I am not sure if I am using things correctly, this gives me an animated brain plot on the right. However, the plot on the left is now not updated but just drawn over. So instead of a sliding bar, I get an expanding color surface. Something like this:

[image]

## Question

How do I

- get the plot on the left to update (as opposed to overwrite) on each iteration when using the function animation method? **I already tried the ax.cla() function in matplotlib but since this also clears all axis attributes (like xlim) this is not a solution for me**. Are there altneratives?
- get the plot on the right to work with the artist animation method even though the custom plotting class is obviously missing a crucial attribute.

Also, I am not sure if I am doing the whole implementation part right, so any advice on that front is also very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may need to clear the `axvspan` axis between plots with `ax.cla()` to get the correct left plot (N.B. probably should clear the right plot too). To get round the problem of missing attributes, I'd suggest extracting the data from the returned handle from `nlp.plot_stat_map` and plotting with matplotlib `pcolormesh` (or `imshow`). Another possibility is creating a child class and adding this method yourself. It may also be worth submitting a bug/feature request to `nilearn` if this should be present.

By the way, if you're only after a quick and easy plot, you can do a poor man's version of animation using interactive plots, as a minimal example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

#Interactive plot
plt.ion()

#Setup figures
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
ay = fig.add_subplot(122)
plt.show()


x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
for i in range(10000):
    print(i)
    #Clear axes
    ax.cla(); ay.cla()

    #Update data
    yx = np.sin(x+i*0.1)
    yy = np.sin(2.*(x+i*0.1))

    #Replot
    ax.plot(x,yx)
    ay.plot(x,yy)

    #Pause to allow redraw
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

Comment: Thanks. I should clarify that ax.cla is not desired because that also resets the axis attributes (such as xlim) on each redraw and thus messes up the plot. I believe my question could be rephrased as: how do I clear the plot without loosing axis attributes?

Comment: Could you not simply reset the axis limits again inside the animation loop? I don't think you can clear the axis without also clearing all other attributes. If the axis must be unchanged, you need to instead update/clear the displayed data objects. The plot handles (`a` and `b`) should have `set_data` method which can be used to change the plot without touching the axes. For example `ax.patches.remove(a)` would remove the current `axvspan` instance. There will be similar removes for other primitive artist objects.